# Touch events over two dom elements?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, web-applications, mobile

I have two dom elements right next to one another.

During a touch event I want to be able to slide over each element. As I do, depending on what element i'm on I want different things to happen.

What would this look like?

Since the touch is down a new touchstart event doesn't fire as they slide to the new element.

Thanks!

EDIT: this is the actual code

```
ul
   li 1
   li 2
   li 3
```

I want to carry a constant touchmove event over each item and all i really need it to be able to know the index of the current `li`

Right now I'm trying:

```
$('ul').live 'touchmove', (event) ->
   element = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY)
   #now i need the index of this element somehow
```

Answer (score 1):

```
element = document.elementFromPoint(event.pageX, event.pageY)
```

**pageX and pageY** not clientX and clientY

It's hard to look into these event objects for touch events because the mobile Safari console is so freaking primitive.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to listen for the "touchmove" event to be triggered. Then use `document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY)` to figure out which div the finger is over.

Comment: Should I be listening for events on the specific divs? Check my edit for my detailed case.

Comment: the index seems to be stuck to the first touchmove event picked up. So if i first hit li index 1 it will be stuck on that for the remander of the drag, see discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815231/jquery-index-of-dom-element Thanks!

Comment: "Should I be listening for events on the specific divs?"
No, you want to listen on the main document. From your edited example, you seem to be using jQuery. Maybe you should consider jQTouch for event handling?