# jQuery index of dom element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have...

```
element = document.elementFromPoint(x, y)
```

then I want to do something like...

```
index = $(element).index()
```

The DOM element is a `li` and I need its position in the list.

Thanks!

EDIT: If what i'm doing is correct then something here is wrong, [Touch events over two dom elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814550/touch-events-over-two-divs/7814791)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: *"...I need its position in the list"* What you already have does exactly that. If it doesn't, then you should verify that `element` is what you expect.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ, well then i'm doing something else wrong, can you check my other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814550/touch-events-over-two-divs/7814791

Comment: Have you verified that `element` is the element you're expecting?

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ I'm having a hard time because I can't log a circular reference in mobile safari.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by circular references in this case, but can you just do an `alert()`? Like `alert(element && element.nodeName);`.

Comment: Are you certain that what you're getting back from `document.elementFromPoint` is an `<li>`?

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ @artlung It picks up a mix of `LI` `UL` and `DIV` so I added `if element.nodeName === 'LI'` but `console.log $(element).index()` is always 0.

Comment: Try `$(element).closest('li').index();`.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ hrrm that always logs `1`

Comment: Oh, wait. If you're getting `0` or `1`, that's an index number. So I'm not sure what the issue is. Are you saying that the index never changes? Do you have nested lists?

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ yes the index never changes as I move from `li` to `li`

Comment: The goal is to trigger different events based on what list item the users finger is placed on during a drag event

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm just not sure. How about you @artlung?

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ ah yea, me neither, the index seems to be stuck to the first touchmove event picked up. So if i first hit li index 1 it will be stuck on that for the remander of the drag

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ the answer is that I should of been using pageX and pageY not clientX and clientY as answered in the other question. Thanks for the help. BTW you should answer this question with your comment, what I had was correct, so I can mark it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works: `index = $(element).index()`

Answer (score 3):

$(element) will work, if you want to know its position you need to select it's preceding siblings.

jQuery than gives you the length property, wich works like on arrays.

```
$(element).prevAll().length;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is `$('li').index(element);`

[`index()`<sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/index/) allows you to pass a selector or DOM element as a parameter to work similarly to `indexOf`.

Comment: This will give index from among all `li` elements on the page.